# Let the paper size fit the print area in Excel

Tags: excel, pdf, printing, pdf-generation

I wrote a 10*5 table in MS Excel 2010. Then I intended to print this table to a PDF file.

By default, it would print this table on a regular page, say Letter(8.5*11). This gives a printed paper with most area are blank.

Can I print this table to a PDF file with minimal blank space?

In another word, let the paper size fit the print area?

Answer (score 0):

If that option did exist, the text would be very large since you effectively just zoomed in..

I recommend looking at your table in Page Layout view (goto **View**->**Page Layout**) and fiddling with the table's rows and columns until it takes up the entire space.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can by setting the normal print area to the area ytou want in the pdf and set the print margin settings to minimal and the Page setting to Fit to  x by y pages.

If that would still leave you with emptiness on your pdf page your area is just to tiny. Increase its size by increasing the Text size inside that area until you see in the PDF save that you fill up the complete area.

Unfortunately there doesnt seem to be a single magic setting for this. You will have to find the size of the "paper"  and that of your text yourself...